# QTranslator and UTF-8 combo give me trouble

Tags: qt

Using Qt 4.7.4 on Mac.

My *.TS files are generated and are UTF-8 using a perl script I wrote. Long story with legacy dependency. We have 13 languages we have to support including some exotic ones. Generating *.QM files out of them seems to work well. You can load the *.QM file into Qt Linguist and everything looks healthy.

Due to legacy reasons, my system langauge is “Enums”. That is, I do something like this:

```
QString label = tr("APP_STRINGS_MYLABEL_TEXT"); // this translates to 13 langauges...
```

so, an excerpt from the english .TS file for instance reads:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE TS>
<TS version="2.0" language="en">
<defaultcodec>UTF-8</defaultcodec>
<context>
  <name>MyApp</name>
    <message>
      <source>APP_STRINGS_MYLABEL_TEXT/source>
      <translation>My Label Text In English</translation>
    </message>
..
..
..
</context>
```

My project file has the following:

```
CODECFORTR = UTF-8
```

My main method has test code that looks like this:

```
QTextCodec::setCodecForTr(QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8"));
QTranslator translator;
bool empty = translator.isEmpty(); // Returns TRUE
bool loaded = translator.load("myApp_en","/Users/user/Dev/myApp/translation");
empty = translator.isEmpty(); // returns FALSE

// install the translator.
MyApp->installTranslator(&translator);

// Here comes my problem...
QString test = MyApp->trUtf8("APP_STRINGS_MYLABEL_TEXT"); // returns "APP_STRINGS_MYLABEL_TEXT"
QString test2 = MyApp->tr("APP_STRINGS_MYLABEL_TEXT"); // returns "APP_STRINGS_MYLABEL_TEXT"
```

As you can see, all my strings are being translated back to their original values. No real translation takes place. If you have any idea why thins might be happening, i’d appreciate the assistance. I am at a loss right now.

Comment: Looks like the translation is loaded but can't be matched to the system locale. What do you get with this?: qDebug() << QLocale::system().uiLanguages();

Comment: uiLanguages() will not pass compilation. Probably deprecated in 4.7.4 - but language() is 31 ("English") which is also the the string I get back from "languageToString(Langauge lang)" method. But wait, there may be something here. When I ask "QLocale::system().name();", I am getting back "en_US". Is this where the mismatch occurs? how do I bridge this?

Comment: I think the country suffix is OK. Qt strips it when trying to locate the translation file: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtranslator.html#load Maybe you can try the other load function?

Comment: Tried recreating the `.ts` files in my project after setting `CODECFORTR = UTF-8` in the pro file. Then translated a few strings and ran `lrelease` to generate the `.qm` files. Everything works exactly as it should.

Comment: @RM1970 do you have `using namespace ..` in your sources? I read [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/linguist-programmers.html#coping-with-c-namespaces) that namespaces can confuse the `lupdate` tool causing the runtime translation of strings to fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit was the context. Since I am using generated strings from a 3rd party source, the context was always wrong. As soon as I started using the "MyApp" context explicitly in the translate API it started working.

thanks to all those who responded.